# ARIMA(1,1,1) throws value error: The model specification cannot be estimated

Tags: python, python-3.x, arima

I'm forecasting website visits using ARIMA model in time-series forecast with Python. Here is main details to get the picture of the process:
[imported modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMFyn.png)

[Data and actual plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwMI4.png)
Figures represent the number of visits. Dates used as index, but as string (formatted date)

[Differences (1 and 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9etQ.png)

[Correlations (auto & Partial)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrZA1.png)

[ARIMA model with (1,1,1) order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE6tm.png)

[ARIMA error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToAYS.png)

So, as you see, for p and q, 1 is the best choice, and differencing 1 is more stationary (and even doesn't work with 2). So, I chose order = (1,1,1) which must best fit, but I get value error result that says:
The model specification cannot be estimated. The model contains 7 regressors (0 trend, 0 seasonal, 7 lags) but after adjustment for hold_back and creation of the lags, there are only 2 data points available to estimate parameters.
It doesn't work for (1,2,1) too, and the same error. However, it works for (0,1,1) which gives not bad q (MA) value (0.01), and with AIC 147.596. But the plot doesn't seem good when comparing with actuals:
[Actual with Forecast (plot_predict())](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXRoU.png)

Please, help to identify the reason why ARIMA gives error for (1,1,1) which must be the best order. How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: One remark - can you add your code to the question's text? It will be much easier to view and edit. Also, if possible, please try to insert pictures to the text - not to external links.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.